# Lubuntu. How to invoke a program from the Activities menu, with an option in the invocation (e.g., -u)

Tags: lubuntu, appmenu

In Lubuntu 20.04.  I want to make the Activities menu invoke a program using a switch. So I think I need to find the file that tells the Activities menu what invocations to use, and modify that file. I've poked around a bit but can't find it. Anybody know where it is, or any other way to make Activities invoke a program with options? Specifically, I want this invocation for florence, an onscreen keyboard:

```
florence -u <configuration filename>
```

Comment: I'm sure this is covered elsewhere, so I'll just leave this as a comment. The easiest way to do this is to install `alacarte`. It says it's for Gnome, but it works just fine in Lubuntu - I just tested it. It'll show up as 'Main Menu' in accessories (after installed) and you can use it to add new items to your start menu. It's pretty self-explanatory as to how you use it.

Comment: Activities menu makes me think of GNOME not LXQt (the menu is called "*Application Menu*" in LXQt, right click on it and you'll see the name & options available for it). Creating a shortcut for it maybe a good option (see https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.14/shortcut_keys.html) or even creating a desktop launcher (https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/5/5.2/desktop_icons.html)  By activities menu, if you mean something else you'll need to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes, I see now that 'Application Menu" is the right term.